# need to align the csv file in proper format

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have one script which is running and giving an csv file as output in the below format

```
25-02-2013          
RJ          
D204349194          
Pagamento Caixa                                                     0   
           256.31    -256.31
```

But i need to align in the below format :

```
25-02-2013  RJ  D244728244  Pagamento Banco Brasil  0   403.25  -403.25
```

Means like in excel it should be divided into columns

please suggest me

Comment: What is the magic transformation that converts 256.31 to 403.25?

Answer (score 1):

if you have `column` installed, try this line:

```
 awk '{printf $0}' file|column -t
```

for your example:

```
kent$  cat file
25-02-2013          
RJ          
D204349194          
Pagamento Caixa                                                     0   
           256.31    -256.31

kent$  awk '{printf $0}' file|column -t
25-02-2013  RJ  D204349194  Pagamento  Caixa  0  256.31  -256.31
```

Comment: You must have trailing whitespace in your input file.  Or you are using a different `awk`.  Also, `column` does not work well if the input does not end in a newline (on OS X).

Comment: @WilliamPursell nice point! my awk is gnu awk 4. I checked input in question, there are trailing spaces. that's why I came up with `printf $0`. with `" "` is certainly safer.

Answer (score 0):

First use `tr` to pull everything onto a single line and then use `sed` to split the single line based on a field.
Try the following:

```
tr '\n' '\t' < file | sed -r 's/([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})/\n\1/g'
```

This assumes that:

- your file is tab delimited
- the first field of each record is a date of the form `dd-MM-yyyy`
- there are no other dates in a record except for the first field

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{$1=$1; printf $0 "  "}' input; echo
```

The `$1=$1` squeezes whitespace on each line, and the `echo` emits a terminating newline.